# How to make `gnome-screenshot` or `flameshot` work in crontab under Wayland?

Tags: gnome, cron, wayland, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 under **GNOME on Wayland**. I want to take the screenshot every minute and save them to a designated folder. The simplest thing I can think of is using `crontab` which is available out-of-the-box in Ubuntu. There are only a handful of programs that can take screenshots under **GNOME on Wayland** - including `gnome-screnshot` and `flameshot`. However despite the fact these programs work from the Ubuntu terminal, they do not work when run in a cron. I guess this problem is specific to Wayland as I was successful in taking screenshot in a cron under **GNOME on Xorg** using `scrot` which is a screenshot program working in X.

I would like to stick to GNOME on Wayland because it has some advantages over X. I would like to know:

- What screenshot software works in crontab under GNOME on Wayland?
- Any workarounds to make `flameshot` or `gnome-screenshot` work in crontab?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd keep that simple and rely on a script with `sleep 60` between the screenshots.

Comment: @HuHa Can you possibility tell me how to make the script run automatically after I log in? Let's say the script only runs for a specific user.

Comment: You could simply add it to that user's autostart directory: Create a .desktop file for the script and put it into that user's `.config/autostart`.

Comment: re: *"I want to take the screenshot every minute and save them to a designated folder."*... why do you want to do this... and why for a specific user? Sounds like a major privacy/spying issue...

Comment: @Huha Thank you for the solution. That works for me well.